# Including a Table in a Figure Environment

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

In order to close the vertical space between this figure and table, I'd like to place the table inside the figure environment.  Is that possible?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows pdf, jpg, png, & tif.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Fancy Header package.
\usepackage{xcolor}

% PAGE GEOMETRY

\setlength{\columnsep}{8 mm}
\textwidth = 6.8 in
\textheight = 9 in
\oddsidemargin = 0 mm
\evensidemargin = -15 mm

% CHANGE COLOR OF SHOWFRAME (PAGE GUIDES)

\colorlet{showframe}{cyan}
\makeatletter
\let\org@Gm@pageframes\Gm@pageframes
\renewcommand*{\Gm@pageframes}{%
  \begingroup
    \color{showframe}%
    \org@Gm@pageframes
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% HEADER / FOOTER

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\bf AS332 F1/M1/B1 Flight Manual} %
\chead{} %
\rhead{\bf 1 June 2014} %
\lfoot{} %
\cfoot{\thepage} %
\rfoot{} %

% BEGIN

\begin{document} % ==============================================================

% RUNTIME TWEAKS

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes rule below header.

% FULL PAGE FIGURE:  INSTRUMENT SUBPANEL (F1-1)

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{instrument_subpanel_f1-1.png}
\caption{Instrument Subpanel (F1-1)}
\label{fig:instsubf11}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}\small\sf
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
1 & windscreen washing pushbuttons\\
2 & emergency battery monitoring and control panel\\
3 & LH windscreen and LH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
4 & aural warning control switches\\
5 & windscreen wiper control switch\\
6 & engine 1 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
7 & overspeed test pushbutton and associated lights\\
8 & engine 2 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
9 & RH windscreen and RH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
10 & power calculator test button
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\clearpage\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Rather than putting the `tabular` into a `table`, you could include it as part of the `figure`.  That way, it won't `float` away.

Comment: @Steven: I thought of that, then failed at that, but I will try again.

Comment: Include only the `tabular` inside the `figure` underneath your `\includegraphics`. You don't need a `table` environment to include a `tabular`; the `tabular` can stand on its own.

Comment: Okay, worked great.  Do you think this is a useful exchange for others?

Comment: as long as the table doesn't have a separate caption that should go into a list of tables, there should be no problem including it directly in the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I describe in my comment.

Other minor changes included `\centering` instead of the `center` environment; `\sffamily` instead of `\sf`; a small `\vspace` after the `\caption`, which can be tuned to suit; and a `[p]` option to `figure` rather than `[t]`, since vertically centering the figure seems nicer to me.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Allows pdf, jpg, png, & tif.
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
%\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
%\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Fancy Header package.
\usepackage{xcolor}

% PAGE GEOMETRY

\setlength{\columnsep}{8 mm}
\textwidth = 6.8 in
\textheight = 9 in
\oddsidemargin = 0 mm
\evensidemargin = -15 mm

% CHANGE COLOR OF SHOWFRAME (PAGE GUIDES)

\colorlet{showframe}{cyan}
\makeatletter
\let\org@Gm@pageframes\Gm@pageframes
\renewcommand*{\Gm@pageframes}{%
  \begingroup
    \color{showframe}%
    \org@Gm@pageframes
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% HEADER / FOOTER

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\bf AS332 F1/M1/B1 Flight Manual} %
\chead{} %
\rhead{\bf 1 June 2014} %
\lfoot{} %
\cfoot{\thepage} %
\rfoot{} %

% BEGIN

\begin{document} % ==============================================================

% RUNTIME TWEAKS

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes rule below header.

% FULL PAGE FIGURE:  INSTRUMENT SUBPANEL (F1-1)

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{instrument_subpanel_f1-1.png}
\caption{Instrument Subpanel (F1-1)\label{fig:instsubf11}}
\vspace{1cm}
\small\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{rl}
1 & windscreen washing pushbuttons\\
2 & emergency battery monitoring and control panel\\
3 & LH windscreen and LH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
4 & aural warning control switches\\
5 & windscreen wiper control switch\\
6 & engine 1 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
7 & overspeed test pushbutton and associated lights\\
8 & engine 2 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
9 & RH windscreen and RH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
10 & power calculator test button
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\clearpage\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The separation between floats in a float page is regulated by the length parameter `\@fpsep`, which has a default value of `10pt plus 2fil`; LaTeX has also `\@fptop` and `\@fpbot` for the space above and below, which have a default value of `0pt plus 1fil`. This means that in a float page the space between the two floats will be twice the white space at top and bottom, plus 10pt.

You can change this behavior by resetting `\@fpsep`.

Please, note also other recommended changes to your input. The `demo` option to `graphicx` is just for this example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Allows pdf, jpg, png, & tif.
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Fancy Header package.
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}

% PAGE GEOMETRY

\geometry{
  columnsep=8mm,
  textwidth = 6.8in,
  textheight = 9in,
  headheight=14.5pt,
}

\makeatletter
\setlength\@fpsep{10pt plus 0.5fil}
\makeatother

% CHANGE COLOR OF SHOWFRAME (PAGE GUIDES)

\colorlet{showframe}{cyan}
\makeatletter
\let\org@Gm@pageframes\Gm@pageframes
\renewcommand*{\Gm@pageframes}{%
  \begingroup
    \color{showframe}%
    \org@Gm@pageframes
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% HEADER / FOOTER

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries AS332 F1/M1/B1 Flight Manual}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries 1 June 2014}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes rule below header.


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] % just [p
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{instrument_subpanel_f1-1.png}
\caption{Instrument Subpanel (F1-1)}
\label{fig:instsubf11}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering\small\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{rl}
1 & windscreen washing pushbuttons\\
2 & emergency battery monitoring and control panel\\
3 & LH windscreen and LH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
4 & aural warning control switches\\
5 & windscreen wiper control switch\\
6 & engine 1 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
7 & overspeed test pushbutton and associated lights\\
8 & engine 2 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
9 & RH windscreen and RH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
10 & power calculator test button
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if your table is just for explaining the figure, put it in the same `figure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}[p] % just [p
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{instrument_subpanel_f1-1.png}
\caption{Instrument Subpanel (F1-1)}
\label{fig:instsubf11}

\bigskip

\small\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{rl}
1 & windscreen washing pushbuttons\\
2 & emergency battery monitoring and control panel\\
3 & LH windscreen and LH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
4 & aural warning control switches\\
5 & windscreen wiper control switch\\
6 & engine 1 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
7 & overspeed test pushbutton and associated lights\\
8 & engine 2 monitoring panel and engine vent switch\\
9 & RH windscreen and RH pitot de-icing control switches and indicator lights\\
10 & power calculator test button
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

There is no law that prescribes `tabular` environment to go in `table` and `\includegraphics` in `figure`. They are just objects to be typeset.